# Using cPanel's AutoSSL when your domain is using Cloudflare

Tags: ssl-certificate, cpanel, cloudflare

My domain `analogue.design` is using Cloudflare's name servers, and caching the A record of `analogue.design`.

Will that prevent AutoSSL from running in cPanel?

Currently I receive an error in AutoSSL:

> DNS DCV: The DNS query to “_cpanel-dcv-test-record.analogue.design”
> for the DCV challenge returned no “TXT” record that matches the value
> “_cpanel-dcv-test-record=4INs3KmEtlH8IwIA2C3vjAbfrkrmLisoUQomsJJ19oPnm23SdoHHnWeFd5AgbU2M”.;
> HTTP DCV: “cPanel (powered by Sectigo)” forbids DCV HTTP redirections.

However, the A records for:

- `autodiscover.analogue.design`
- `_cpanel-dcv-test-record.analogue.design`

are not being cached, they are DNS only.

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,
If you are using cloudflare as proxy server and if you want to install Autossl Certificate on your server, then you have to pause the cloudflare for your server.

To pause click on overview on the bottom right corner you can see pause cloudflare,
then go to ssl in cpanel, install the certificate using AutoSSL,
it will install the certificate , then again go to cloudflare and run it back

Answer (score 1):

On Cloudflare temporarily disable "Always Use HTTPS" in "SSL/TLS" > "Edge Certificates". Then Run AutoSSL. This is happening on cPanel when using Cloudflare, but not DirectAdmin from my experience.

Comment: Do you know if there's a way to automate the process? I'm tired of being reminded of doing it manually myself.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are adding those records as A record entry and not as txt record with the values provided against them in cloudflare.

Manually check using mxtool or some other online tool available if those needed records are reflecting or not. ( https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=mx%3aanalogue.design&run=toolpage) , it also says not found.

Usually adding those records works for renewing the SSL via autoSSL in cPanel for cloudflare based websites, so probably you are doing something wrong while adding those txt records as explained above.

Quick way would be turn off orange cloud to grey and run the autoSSL, however, you will need to repeat this after every months so not a suggested solution.